# Change HTML element's CSS style using java

Tags: java, html, css

I am using JSP to create my web page. I need to use java classes to access the data that I need to pull from another website's JSON (this CANNOT change).

Say I have the code:

```
<div class="fruit apple"></div>
<div class="fruit banana"></div>
//"fruit peach", "fruit orange", and so on...
style.fruit {display: none;}
```

I need to change the HTML element using JAVA, not javascript. In my JSP file, it will be in a <% %> tag.

```
<% var divClassINeedToChange = "banana";
//some sort of JAVA code that is equivalent to:
//document.getElementsByClass(divClassINeedToChange).style.display = "block"; %>
```

I cannot find the line of java code that is equivalent to the above line.

Comment: send an ajax request to java servlet and update html using the response

Comment: @JunedAhsan could you further explain?

Comment: You need to so searching and reading...input boxes here will not be able to contain the description

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you

you can parse your page using DOM or SAX parser.

for example

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc=builder.parse(new File(filename));
Element e = doc.getElemetById(divClassINeedToChange);
```

Comment: What files do I need to download/import in order to use this? @m.hassaballah

Comment: // JAXP api
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
 
// DOM api
import org.w3c.dom.*;